# Adding functions y(x) together in python - impossible?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, math, lambda

I'm currently trying to solve an engineering problem where I need to solve relatively long differential equations, for which I'm using the method [odeint](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) from scipy. I changed my problem to more easy variables and equations to shorten the code below and make it clearer.

I want to add two parts of a function, here `f` and `g`, to build my final equation `dydt`. Both parts have the same variables `y,x` and other different constant arguments.

I get the error *"unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'function' and 'function'"*.

Is there a way around this?
I assume I could try to use `lambda` but I'm fairly new to python, and couldn't figure a way to make it work.

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint  
  
def f(y, x, arg1, arg2):
        f_result = y + x + arg1 * arg2
        return f_result

def g(y, x, arg3, arg4, arg5):
        g_result = y * x * (arg3 + arg4 + arg5)
        return g_result

def equation(fun1, fun2):
        dydt = fun1 + fun2
        return dydt

y0, x_span, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5 = 0, [x for x in range(11)] , 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

f_fun = f
g_fun = g
dydt = equation(f_fun, g_fun)

sol = odeint(dydt, y0, x_span, args=(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5))
```

Comment: Hello! Would you mind showing us what would dydt look like? Is it just `f(y, x, arg1, arg2) + g(y, x, arg3, arg4, arg5)` or is the result that you expect more complicated than this?

Comment: Nevermind, i looked a bit more in the odeint documentation. Gonna give you some examples.

Comment: The real function is a little more complicated but the idea is the same - there is one independent variable (x), one dependent variable (y) and a few constants. So, in the case of the code above, dydt would be simply `dydt = y + x + (arg1 * arg2) + y * x * (arg3 + arg4 + arg5) `. Then, the odeint method would solve for `y`

Comment: I guess the core of the problem is to know whether it's possible to bring two functions together and then solve the resulting function with a method...I could just write them both together as I did above but the code would be much more adaptable to other similar problems if I could split different parts of the main equation to solve in individual functions, like here `f` and `g` or more. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Hmm, i posted a first answer but i realize it's not what you asked now. Let me search a little bit more.

Comment: I wonder if your equations are really coupled.  It's hard to tell from your example, but integration schemes usually take an array of first order terms to integrate.  Your descriptions reads as if you really want an array dydx(2), where dydx[0] = f and dydx[1] = g.  Integrate them together as a system of equations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build that kind of stuff, but it will not be very easy to maintain. Your problem here is that you want to return a function from a function. You can do this easily in python because you can define a function inside one, and return it.

Where it gets hard is that your "inner" functions will require different arguments every time, so managing to build dynamically another function that will have the right signature is... Well, as you will see, it's not *that* hard, it will just not necessarily be the easiest to maintain.

A very raw way to do what you want is this:

```py
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def f(y, x, arg1, arg2):
    f_result = y + x + arg1 * arg2
    return f_result

def g(y, x, arg3, arg4, arg5):
    g_result = y * x * (arg3 + arg4 + arg5)
    return g_result

def equation(fun1, fun2):
    def inner(*args):
        y = args[0]
        x = args[1]
        arg1 = args[2]
        arg2 = args[3]
        arg3 = args[4]
        arg4 = args[5]
        arg5 = args[6]
        dydt = fun1(x, y, arg1, arg2) + fun2(x, y, arg3, arg4, arg5)
        return dydt
    return inner

y0, x_span, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5 = 0, [x for x in range(11)], 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

f_fun = f
g_fun = g
dydt = equation(f_fun, g_fun)

sol = odeint(dydt, y0, x_span, args=(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5))
```

`inner` takes `*args` as arguments, which means "any number of arguments, as a list". As you can see i precised how to extract each value from it to rebuild our function.

Here, this is really raw and straightforward. If you want to actually make it a bit more permissive, you can try to guess the number of args your functions `f` and `g` require by inspecting them, so f and g can change a bit.

warning: using some relatively advanced techniques from now on.Mostly [argument unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments)

```py
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from inspect import signature

def f(y, x, arg1, arg2):
    f_result = y + x + arg1 * arg2
    return f_result

def g(y, x, arg3, arg4, arg5):
    g_result = y * x * (arg3 + arg4 + arg5)
    return g_result

def equation(fun1, fun2):
    def inner(*args):
        y = args[0]
        x = args[1]
        fun_args = (x for x in list(args[2:]))
        fun1_args = [next(fun_args) for _ in range(len(signature(fun1).parameters) - 2)] # We remove 2 because y and x are always there
        fun2_args = [next(fun_args) for _ in range(len(signature(fun2).parameters) - 2)]
        dydt = fun1(x, y, *fun1_args) + fun2(x, y, *fun2_args)
        return dydt
    return inner

y0, x_span, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5 = 0, [x for x in range(11)], 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

f_fun = f
g_fun = g
dydt = equation(f_fun, g_fun)

sol = odeint(dydt, y0, x_span, args=(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5))
```

And for good measure, you could even decide to do an arbitrary number of functions, as long as you always put the parameters in the right order!

```py
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from inspect import signature

def f(y, x, arg1, arg2):
    f_result = y + x + arg1 * arg2
    return f_result

def g(y, x, arg3, arg4, arg5):
    g_result = y * x * (arg3 + arg4 + arg5)
    return g_result

def equation(*args):
    def inner(*inner_args):
        y = inner_args[0]
        x = inner_args[1]
        dydt = []
        fun_args = (x for x in list(inner_args[2:]))
        for func in args:
            func_args = [next(fun_args) for _ in range(len(signature(func).parameters) - 2)] # We remove 2 because y and x are always there
            dydt.extend(func(x, y, *func_args))
        return sum(dydt)
    return inner

y0, x_span, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5 = 0, [x for x in range(11)], 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

f_fun = f
g_fun = g
dydt = equation(f_fun, g_fun)

sol = odeint(dydt, y0, x_span, args=(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5))
```

The real question now is, is it really more maintainable that way?

Here's how i'd do it, personnally, allowing for some quick modifications witout it being too complicated.

```py
def equation(y, x, *fun_args):
    def f():
        arg1, arg2 = *fun_args[0]
        f_result = y + x + arg1 * arg2
        return f_result

    def g():
        arg3, arg4, arg5 = *fun_args[1]
        g_result = y * x * (arg3 + arg4 + arg5)
        return g_result

    return f() + g()

y0, x_span, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5 = 0, [x for x in range(11)], 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

sol = odeint(equation, y0, x_span, args=((arg1, arg2), (arg3, arg4, arg5)))
```

This allows me only to play with the inner part of the "equation" function, as long as i pass the correct args in `sol = odeint(equation, y0, x_span, args=((arg1, arg2), (arg3, arg4, arg5)))`. I also regrouped function parameters in tuple for better visiblity.

Comment: Wow that makes a lot of sense! I was thinking about putting the parameters somehow in a separate variable but didn’t know how. Now I get it! Thanks for the explanation, I really appreciated it!

Comment: Glad to help :) Do not forget to accept the answer if it is enough for you, to kinda "close" the question.

Comment: Sorry! just did it now :) I cannot upvote yet, but I checked the green checkmark!